# Add markers to an image Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hey I have an image like this:
[image]

I need to add markers on the image and have click events on each marker.
I am looking for angularjs library which knows how to do it?
I don't want any jquery library or javascript solution.I need a solution in the level of angularjs.

Comment: AngularJS is javascript..Thus you will use a javascript solution..AngularJS itself cant handle maps. You should use a 3rd party library

Comment: Flagged to be closed because "**Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**"

Comment: ok you can close this post,I will handle it alone.

Comment: thats the coder's spirit@Brk